# (Crowdsourced) Dataset with label/annotation metadata like duration/quality

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, dataset

I'm looking for a research project for datasets (the more the better), potentially crowdsourced, which go beyond basic feature vectors + labels, and include additionally some metadata about the labels. Specifically I'd like the annotation time, or some other cost metric, and if the dataset was crowdsourced, the individual labels per annotator. On top, some measure of the quality of the labels by different annotators would be helpful as well. The Dataset domain is not relevant.

Also I'm not sure if https://datascience.stackexchange.com is the right place to ask for that, but maybe you can help me.

So far I could only find [this](https://bmcresnotes.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/s13104-019-4858-z) dataset.

Comment: This question may be a better for https://opendata.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Oh thanks, didn't know that one existed!

Answer (score 1):

I did a project with the [CheXpert dataset](https://stanfordmlgroup.github.io/competitions/chexpert/) which includes metadata and labels for uncertainty. I don't know if it's the right kind of metadata you are looking for. In general, medical datasets usually contain metadata. A similar one would be from the [NIH](https://www.nih.gov/news-events/news-releases/nih-clinical-center-provides-one-largest-publicly-available-chest-x-ray-datasets-scientific-community).

Otherwise, [this](https://paperswithcode.com/datasets) is a decent index of high quality datasets.

Comment: No, CheXpert is not what I'm looking for. Apparently the used multiple experts for the labels of the validation set, but not even the individual labels per annotator are provided, metadata like the duration of how long it took the annotator to label the samples. Same applies to the NIH one.